# Pandas - Randomly Replace 10% of rows with other rows

Tags: python, pandas

I want to randomly select 10% of all rows in my df and replace each with a randomly sampled existing row from the df.

To randomly select 10% of rows `rows_to_change = df.sample(frac=0.1)` works and I can get a new random existing row with `replacement_sample = df.sample(n=1)` but how do I put this together to quickly iterate over the entire 10%?

The df contains millions of rows x ~100 cols.

Example df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15],'B':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15],'C':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]})

    A   B   C
0   1   1   1
1   2   2   2
2   3   3   3
3   4   4   4
4   5   5   5
5   6   6   6
6   7   7   7
7   8   8   8
8   9   9   9
9   10  10  10
10  11  11  11
11  12  12  12
12  13  13  13
13  14  14  14
14  15  15  15
```

Let's say it randomly samples indexes 2,13 to replace with randomly selected indexes 6,9 the final df would look like:

```
    A   B   C
0   1   1   1
1   2   2   2
2   7   7   7
3   4   4   4
4   5   5   5
5   6   6   6
6   7   7   7
7   8   8   8
8   9   9   9
9   10  10  10
10  11  11  11
11  12  12  12
12  13  13  13
13  10  10  10
14  15  15  15
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a random sample, then take another random sample of the same size and replace the values at those indices with the original sample.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(1,15), 'B': range(1,15), 'C': range(1,15)})

samp = df.sample(frac=0.1)
samp
# returns:
    A   B   C
6   7   7   7
9  10  10  10

replace = df.loc[~df.index.isin(samp.index)].sample(samp.shape[0])
replace
# returns:
   A  B  C
3  4  4  4
7  8  8  8

df.loc[replace.index] = samp.values
```

This copies the rows without replacement

```
df
# returns:
     A   B   C
0    1   1   1
1    2   2   2
2    3   3   3
3    7   7   7
4    5   5   5
5    6   6   6
6    7   7   7
7   10  10  10
8    9   9   9
9   10  10  10
10  11  11  11
11  12  12  12
12  13  13  13
13  14  14  14
14  15  15  15
```

To sample with replacement, use the keyword `replace = True` when defining `samp`

Answer (score 1):

@James' answer is a smart Pandas solution.  However, given that you noted your dataset length is somewhere in the millions, you could also consider NumPy given that Pandas often comes with significant performance overhead.

```
def repl_rows(df: pd.DataFrame, pct: float):
    # Modifies `df` inplace.
    n, _ = df.shape
    rows = int(2 * np.ceil(n * pct))  # Total rows in both sets
    idx = np.arange(n, dtype=np.int)  # dtype agnostic
    full = np.random.choice(idx, size=rows, replace=False)
    to_repl, repl_with = np.split(full, 2)
    df.values[to_repl] = df.values[repl_with]
```

Steps:

- Get target rows as an integer.
- Get a NumPy range-array the same length as your index.  Might provide more stability than using the index itself if you have something like an uneven datetime index.  (I'm not totally sure, something to toy around with.)
- Sample from this index without replacement, sample size is 2 times the number of rows you want to manipulate.
- Split the result in half to get targets and replacements.  Should be faster than two calls to `choice()`.
- Replace at positions `to_repl` with values from `repl_with`.